# -q inside Makefile assignment

Tags: make, bash-expansion

Been checking a Makefile which contains:

```
ifdef REALLY_QUIET
  export REALLY_QUIET
  ECHO := true
  LFLAGS := $(LFLAGS) -q
  YFLAGS := $(YFLAGS) -q
endif
```

Could you please point me at what's the meaning of the -q term on the last two assignments (:=)? I checked https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable but I think the -q or --question mentioned there is for the "make" command and not for the content of the Makefile.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LFLAGS := $(LFLAGS) -q
```

appends `-q` to the value currently in `LFLAGS`, and sets `LFLAGS` to the result (as a [simply-expanded variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), since it’s set using `:=`).

This affects whatever command is given elsewhere using `$(LFLAGS)`, adding the `-q` option to it. It doesn’t have anything to do with running `make`. Given the context I imagine that in both cases (`LFLAGS` and `YFLAGS`), `-q` makes the corresponding command run quietly.